# Golang map or struct to add or remove from list

Tags: arrays, go

I have a server and I wan't each connection to be saved into a list. Lets say:

```
type Connection struct {
   Id uint16
   Conn *conn.TCP
}

var connections []Connection
```

But what I wanted to remove / fetch the specific connection id? What should I use?

I was thinking of something like:

```
func GetConnectionById(id uint16) Connection {
    for k, v := range connections {
       if v.Id == id {
          return v
       }
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If they are all numeric `Id`'s couldn't you potentially add them all to an array and set the key to the numeric Id?

Comment: @OliverQueen something like `make(map[uint16]Connection)`?

Comment: YES, exactly what I was saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not identify each `Connection` in a map by its `Id`?

```
package main

type Connection struct {
   Id uint16
   X string
}

var connections map[uint16]Connection

func main() {
    connections = make(map[uint16]Connection)
    connections[1] = Connection{}
}
```

Comment: Yah, I just realized when OliverQueen asked me in the comments :D

Comment: is it possible to have this map globally?

Comment: The way this happens, if you initialize the arr outside of the func, then set the global initialized arr's value to the new one declared within the main function, it should work.